# Outlook 365 Profile - XenDesktop

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I have Outlook 365 installed (In fact Office 365) on our VDI environment (image).

I have the UPM profile setup and it also created an Outlook folder and the XML document is there in the Outlook folder, but every time I launch the desktop and open Outlook on the desktop it keeps updating the mailbox, sent items and other folders. Is this a normal behavior or something else needs to be done?

Sometimes, I even got prompted to login to my Office 365 account. We have On Prem Exchange servers and we are using Office 365. I have setup the registry settings for Autodiscover that has helped me not pointing the logon screen all the time which it stopped after that, but these are the current issues I am facing on the VDI.

I know this is more of an Outlook question that I am posting here. But, I would like to get some info from the experts here has anyone faced the same issue or what is the solution for it to not to keep up updating the Inbox and fetching mails from Inbox, sent items and other folders.

Answer (score 0):

> > but every time I launch the desktop and open Outlook on the desktop it keeps updating the mailbox, sent items and other folders. Is this a normal behavior or something else needs to be done?

It’s normal that Outlook will update all folder at startup, but this won’t take a long time.

If Outlook was stuck at updating folders, we may check following aspects:

1. corrupted Data file

You may encounter this issue if the data file is corrupted. Please [repair data files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253) to test the results.

2. large mailbox size

If the mailbox is very large, updating may take a long time. We may [archive mailbox](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/archive-items-manually-ecf54f37-14d7-4ee3-a830-46a5c33274f6) to see if it helps.

3. third-party add-ins

We can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.

> > even got prompted to login to my Office 365 account.

Do you mean Outlook prompt for activation?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it would prompt for Activation also. Like this morning I logged in, and it started asking me to activate it again. This is in a Citrix VDI environment. My problem is we have Exchange servers On Prem and not all users have account on the cloud with Office 365/Outlook 365. Most of the users at least 25 desktop users will login to their virtual desktops and launch Outlook. It used to prompt with the userID and password that we use for our computers (which is correct) but if we enter the password, it keeps on prompting. With Autodiscover registry it takes you to office 365 login.

Comment: We do not wan the users to login with the Office 365 account, but with their domain credentials that they use for launching outlook. How can this be achieved in Citrix virtual desktop?

Comment: I checked with another user who is testing. He logged onto the virtual desktop and then launched Outlook. The initial Activate login screen came up. He clicked on the x and it closed but he was able to view the mails and send and receive. So, now the only screen at least for this user that is popping up initially is "Sign in to setup Office" and it has all those icons and then Sign in and Create Account option. If he clicks the X on this screen, he goes straight to mails.